# Excel chart to show number of occurences by date and time

Tags: excel, graph, charts, bubble-chart

I'm trying to create what (to me) seems like a simple chart but trying to get Excel to understand what I want isn't quite so simple!

Basically, I am tracking the number of occurences of an event by hour and date, so I have data in 3 columns: date, hour, & number, so it looks like this:

```
date  time  amount
10/01 09:00 1
10/01 10:00 2
10/01 11:00 1
10/01 14:00 1
10/01 15:00 1
10/01 18:00 2
10/01 19:00 1
10/01 20:00 1
10/01 22:00 2
11/01 09:00 1 
11/01 11:00 1
11/01 12:00 1
11/01 13:00 2
11/01 14:00 1
11/01 17:00 1
11/01 19:00 2
11/01 21:00 1
```

I had seen the bubble chart in Excel where the bubble goes larger depending on the data & thought that this would be ideal, but I can't get it to work. I ideally wanted the date on the X-axis, the time on the Y-axis and the number in the 3rd column to be represented by the size of the bubble, but Excel doesn't seem to want to do this. It will put dates along the X-axis, but the Y-axis contains random values such as 09:36, 04:48, 00:00, 19:12, & 14:24 - I have no idea why as all the times are xx:00.

Can anyone help me do thus (or suggest some other type of chart that would work as well/better)?

Answer (score 1):

Those value on the Y axis **ARE** times. Excel is just trying to scale them.  Format the axis manually,and set the Major units to something 0.125 (for three hours) or whatever you want.  For excel 1hr = 1/24

Here is one example.  I set an upper value on the Y-axis of 1.25, to keep the top bubble from being cutoff, but you can change that and the style.

[image]

*Note:  My dates are mdy.  If yours are dmy, your x-axis will have 10-Jan and 11-Jan instead of the dates I show above.*

[image]